# Encoding Special Characters in Perl

Tags: html, perl, encoding

I have this string for example:

```
This is an example text ã&"><£
```

When I run this Perl code on the string:

```
my($string)= @_;
$string =~ s/>//g;
$string =~ s/<//g;
$string =~ s/&/and/g;
$string  =~ s/\"//g;
$string  =~ s/-//;
$string  =~ s/ó//;
$string =~ s/;//g;
$string =~ s/&/&amp;/g;

$string = encode_entities($string, '<>&"');
$string = encode_utf8($string);

return $string;
```

I receive this result:

```
This is an example text ã£ã£
```

Instead of the expected one:

```
This is an example text ã&amp;&quot;&gt;&lt;£
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show your complete script. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Hi, I edited the question above with full script. Are those lines: $string =~ s/>//g; remove the special characters?

Comment: Yes the code you show remove some characters and replaces some others. I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to perl and it's not a code I wrote. Just to understand, this line of code: $string =~ s/&/&amp;/g; removes the & from my string?

Comment: Try run `echo "&1&2" | perl -pE 's/&/&amp;/g'` you see it replaces the string "&1&2" with "&amp1;&amp2;"

Comment: Why do you expect `&` to still be in the string after you removed it with `$string =~ s/&/and/g;`?

Comment: Hi TLP, actually I thought so too but there's no 'and' substring also inside my string. And even when I removed this line  $string =~ s/&/and/g; it's still not there...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following script:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(utf-8));
use HTML::Entities;

my $string = 'This is an example text ã&"><£';
$string = encode_entities($string, '<>&"');
say $string;
```

**Output**:

```
This is an example text ã&amp;&quot;&gt;&lt;£
```